# Why do I need to initialize an int variable to 0?

Tags: c++, initialization

I just made this program which asks to enter number between 5 and 10 and then it counts the sum of the numbers which are entered. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,i,c;
    cout << "Enter the number between 5 and 10" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    if (a < 5 || a > 10)
    {
        cout << "Wrong number" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=1; i<=a; i++)
    {
        c=c+i;
    }
    cout << "The sum of the first " << a << " numbers are " << c << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter `5`, it should display

> The sum of the first 5 numbers are 15

but it displays

> The sum of the first 5 numbers are 2293687

When I set `c` to `0`, it works correctly.

So what is the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because C++ doesn't automatically set it zero for you. So, you should initialize it yourself:

```
int c = 0;
```

An uninitialized variable has a random number such as `2293687`, `-21`, `99999`, ... (If it doesn't invoke *undefined behavior* when reading it)

Also, `static` variables will be set to their default value. In this case `0`.

Comment: If c is declared and initialized like you wrote, would it sit in the stack area?

Comment: @tomer.z: It depends on where you write it. For example, in the global area or in a function declaration...

Answer (score 8):

If you don't set `c` to `0`, it can take any value (technically, an indeterminate value). If you then do this

c = c + i;

then you are adding the value of `i` to something that could be anything. Technically, this is *undefined behaviour*. What happens in practice is that you cannot rely on the result of that calculation.

In C++, non-static or global built-in types have no initialization performed when "default initialized". In order to zero-initialize an `int`, you need to be explicit:

```
int i = 0;
```

or you can use *value initialization*:

```
int i{};
int j = int();
```

Comment: the last line could also be reduced to `int j();` for local variables.

Comment: @unknown6656 That would be a function declaration.

Comment: Yes, nevermind. However, 'int j(0);' should be legal, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Non-static variables are, by definition, uninitialized - their initial values are undefined.

On another compiler, you might get the right answer, another wrong answer, or a different answer each time.

C/C++ don't do extra work (initialization to zero involves at least an instruction or two) that you didn't ask them to do.

Answer (score 0):

> The sum of the first 5 numbers are 2293687

This is because without initializing `c` you are getting value previous stored at that location (garbage value). This will make yor program's behavior undefined. You must have to initialize `c` before using it in your program.

```
int c= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do:

```
int a,i,c;
```

thus instantiating and initializing `c`, you haven't said what you want it initialized to.  The rules here are somewhat complex, but what it boils down to is two things:

1. For integral types, if you don't specify an initializer, the variable's value is *indeterminate*
2. When you try to read an uninitialized variable, you evoke Undefined Behavior