# C++ how to understand (auto & n : v)?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

With the help of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51911467), I wrote a function that outputs the sum of a vector. I want to ask:

- <s>why the first version works, and why the second version does not work.</s>  ( Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665876/why-do-i-need-to-initialize-an-int-variable-to-0). )
- how to understand `for (auto & n : v)`? I understand code like `for (auto ptr = v.begin(); ptr != v.end(); ptr++)` but 1) why we pass `& n` instead of `n`? Also what's the `:v`?

Thanks!

```
// version 1 that works 
int sumVector(vector<int> v){
    int sum_of_vec = 0;
    for (auto &n: v){
        sum_of_vec += n;
    }
    return sum_of_vec;
}

// version 2 that does not work
int sumVector(vector<int> v){
    int sum_of_vec;    // do not specify sum_of_vec = 0
    for (auto &n: v){
        sum_of_vec += n;
    }
    return sum_of_vec;
}
```

(the original question contains two parts that are not entirely covered by the possible duplicate post )

Comment: In the second version sum_of_vec is not initialized to 0. It as an undeterminate value. Then sum_of_vec += n; is undefined behavior: that means you are confusing the compiler. So you can not expect anything good from the second version.

Comment: You should compile with all warnings. For gcc and clang this is option `-Wall`. It will give you a friendly explanation about what is wrong: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/tRkMu6)

Comment: @Oliv thanks. The error message there is very clear.

Comment: You could also just use the wheel the standard library already invented for you. Throw this out and invoke `res =  std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);` at the call site.

Comment: `for (auto & n : v)` is [a range based for loop.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Are you asking why the range declaration of variable `n` is of `auto&`  instead of `auto` type?

Comment: `auto & n` is used instead of `auto n` to avoid a potentially expensive copy. `n` is a reference to a value in the vector instead of a copy. It probably won't make much of a difference with an `int`, but if you had a vector of large strings, the time spend copying could negatively impact the performance of your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['colon' and 'auto' in for loop c++? need some help understanding the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490236/colon-and-auto-in-for-loop-c-need-some-help-understanding-the-syntax)

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the specification. I never knew we could use `&` to modify the type specified by `auto` as well. Guess I need to read more on both `auto` and the link you sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining an object of a built-in type without initialization it will get default initialized. However, default initialization for built-in types actually does nothing! As a result, reading the value of an uninitialized is undefined behavior! Before you can read from a corresponding object it needs to be initialized!

The reason for this somewhat odd behavior is that it is needed for two reasonably important use cases:

- When allocating [huge] arrays of objects it is common the they’ll receive a non-default value from some source and value initializing them would unnecessarily waste time.
- When constructing an object into a region of memory mapped I/O it may not be possible to write to the corresponding location at all or it could have adverse effects.

To support both of these use cases objects built-in types go uninitialized when nothing is specified. It is easy enough to give the objects a value: just specify a value or *value initialize* the object, e.g.:

```
int sum_of_vec{};
```

Comment: Just to follow up with some further details.. as stated in _C++ Primer_ page 43 - 44, "the value of an object of a built-in type that is not explicitly initialized depends on **where** is it defined".1) Variables defined **outside** of any function body are initialized to zero. 2) Variables of built-in types that are defined **inside** functions are unintialized and values are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Second version is ill formed. Variable `sum_of_vec` is not initialized and it will have indeterminate value. This can lead to undefined behaviour.