# Calculating the sum of an array of differences

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a code that calculates the mean of an array of 10 numbers then calculates the difference between the mean and each number. Now I need to add up all the differences but I don't know how. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int sum,mean,difference;

int main(void) {
  int i,j;

  int n[10] = {1,7,5,8,3,5,6,8,2,15};

  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++ ){
    sum = sum + n[j];
  }
 
  mean = sum/10;
  printf("mean = %d\n",mean);

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    difference = mean - n[i];
    printf("difference = %d\n",difference);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a new variable for the sum of differences and do the same like you did for calculating the mean.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int sum,mean,difference,sum_difference;

int main(void) {
  int i,j;

  int n[10] = {1,7,5,8,3,5,6,8,2,15};

  for(j = 0; j < 10; j++ ){
    sum = sum + n[j];
  }
 
  mean = sum/10;
  printf("mean = %d\n",mean);
  
  sum_difference = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     difference = mean - n[i];
     printf("difference = %d\n",difference);
     if(difference < 0) difference = -difference;  // if difference is considered positive
     sum_difference += difference;
  }
    printf("sum_difference = %d\n",sum_difference);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to hard by your descrption. But there are some pitfalls.
For example you should consider value overflows (decide for int or long) and data types etc.
There is some abs (absolute) function that I now do not know how to invoke at the moment so I made the absolute via if.

```
int sumOfDifference = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  int localDifference = mean - n[i];

  if (localDifference < 0)
    localDifference = 0 - localDifference;

  sumOfDifference += localDifference;
}

printf("sum of difference = %d\n",sumOfDifference);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points you need to look at in your code.

1. Do you really need the `math.h` library for this code? Seeing the question that you've made, it seems that this library is not needed here.
2. You have not initialised the sum variable to any value (`0` in this case). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665876/8484779) for more details on how this might give a garbage answer to your code (the language there is `c++` though but it's valid for almost all programming language).
3. The `mean` variable should not be an integer. You got lucky here cause all the values in your array adds up to a number divisible by `10`. Suppose the `sum` came out to be 49, then you'd run into trouble. Similarly then, you need to define the variable `difference` as a `float` also.

All this being said, coming back to your question, to add up all the differences, initialise a `float` variable (say `sum_diff`) to 0 at the beginning. Then in the second `for` loop, just modify the code to something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    difference = mean - n[i];
    sum_diff+=difference;
  }
```

Now just print `sum_diff` outside the loop to see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the mean as:
const int mean = std::accumulate(n, n + 10, 0) / 10;

Then:
`int sumOfDifference = 0;`
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
int localDifference = mean - n[i];
sumOfDifference += abs(localDifference);
}
printf("sum of difference = %d\n", sumOfDifference);