# Implementing square() without using the multiplication operator

Tags: c++, for-loop

Task:

Implement square() without using the multiplication operator; that is, do the
x*x by repeated addition (start a variable result at 0 and add x to it x times).
Then run some version of "the first program" using that square().

Solution #1:

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result = 0; // same output of we declare result without initializing
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            result += x;
        }
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

Output: 19.

Solution #2:

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            return result += x;
        }
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

Output: 19.

Solution #3:

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            return result += x;
        }
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

Output: 22006.

Why does only the third one work?

Comment: None of them are working.

Comment: You're just getting lucky that the third one *appears* to work with your testing.   The first and third both have undefined behaviour, and one possible consequence of undefined behaviour is sometimes passing one or more test cases and appearing to work.   The first falls off the end of a function with non-`void` return, hence undefined behaviour.   The third adds values to an uninitialised variable and returns the result, hence undefined behaviour.   The second has well defined behaviour, but returns before completing the required calculation.

Comment: @Peter Personally, I think he's *unlucky* that it worked - it's always better when it crashes because at least you know you did something wrong - if it accidentally works you learn that code like that works, and then later it doesn't work in production and you have no idea why it failed.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - I agree.   In fact, I normally write something like "getting lucky (or unlucky, depending on how you look at it)" but I wrote that comment rather quickly.   I also suspect it's a subtlety that is lost on too many people - particularly those who believe that testing provides guarantees that something works.

Comment: @Peter  True enough.  There are lots of people that think a passing test is all you need.

Comment: ```int square( int x ) { return x > 1 ? square( x - 1 ) + ( x << 1 ) - 1 : 1; }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution #1**

You don't return result, thus you calculate it but never return it

i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result = 0; // same output of we declare result without initializing
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            result += x;
        }
        return result;
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

**Solution #2**

You return the result after the first iteration, this will always return `x`'s value.

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            result += x;               // remove "return" here
        }
        return result;
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

**Solution #3**

This is an interesting one. With languages like C++, you need to initialize your variables such as integers, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665893/4628115) for more info. Since you don't initialize it, your the integer gets a memory allocation and what ever is in memory at that point is what your int value is now. Since you only add to it, it will add the calculation to that value.

Thus, you need:

```
#include <iostream>
    int square(int x){
        int result = 0;                     // initialize values
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            result += x;                    // remove return here
        }
        return result;                      // return result here
    }
int main() {
    std::cout << square(19);
}
```

Comment: *Since you don't initialize it, your the integer gets a memory allocation and what ever is in memory at that point...* Or the memory has the uninitialized flag set and faults (ABEND) because it was never initialized.  UB.  Funny stuff can happen.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is invalid code: the function `square` is declared as `int`, but doesn't return anything.
2. You return prematurely, during the first iteration of the loop.
3. Same as #2, but with unitialized variable `result` - garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have understood the task you have to accomplish. And you're very close to the result. But there's several major issues, which is why none of the provided solutions work.

## Solution 1

You seem to be doing the task correctly, but never return the result. The fact that the output returns 19 in your case is surprising, but it won't always be like that. See [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:6,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:6,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:6,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:6,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A++++int+square(int+x)%7B%0A++++++++int+result+%3D+0%3B+//+same+output+of+we+declare+result+without+initializing%0A++++++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+x%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++++++result+%2B%3D+x%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+square(19)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:58.02774687715759,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:41.97225312284242,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:41.97225312284242,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

## Solution 2

You might to read up again on `return`. It returns the value *immediately*. So in essence, you're only doing one pass inside the loop, so you're only returning the parameter of the function, which in this case is `19`.

## Solution 3

This one has the same issue with `return` than the previous one. But you're also adding to an uninitialised value of `result`, and because of that can have litterally any possible value inside of it. Which is why you're getting a weird number as a result.

For Solution 1, never returning a value inside a function that expects a return value, and in Solution 3, accessing the value of an uninitialised value, are called `undefined behaviours`. In short, never have `undefined behaviour` in your code, it might work some times on some machines/compilers, but most of the time it will simply not work, or worse, "work" but in unpredictable ways, causing major issues and bugs.